# how do I check that two slices of numpy arrays are the same (or overlapping)?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to check if two ndarrays are overlapping views of the same underlying ndarray.

To check that two slices are exactly the same, I can do something like:

```
a.base is b.base and a.shape == b.shape and a.data == b.data
```

The comparison of buffers seemed to work in one simple case -- can anyone tell me if it works in general?

Unfortunately, this wont work for overlapping slices, and I haven't figured out how to extract from the buffer exactly what its offset is in the underlying data -- perhaps someone can help me with this?

Also, say `a` and `b` are slices of `x`, and `c` is a slice of `b`. As the underlying data is the same, I would also like to detect overlaps between `c` and `a`. It would seem that I should be able to get away with comparing just buffer and shape... if anyone could tell me exactly how, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`numpy.may_share_memory()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html) is the best heuristic that we have at the moment. It is conservatively heuristic; it may give you false positives, but it will not give you false negatives. I think there might be ways to improve the heuristic to be 100% correct. If they pan out, they will be folded into that function, so that's the best way forward.

Comment: What sort of cases might I expect to fail? If its just staggered slices with non-unity step that generate false positive, I can live with that....

Comment: `x[0::2]` / `x[1::2]`. `x[:, 0:5]`, `x[:, 5:10]`. `x = np.dstack(*args); np.may_share_memory(x[0], x[1])`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to compare where the indices live in memory using the [`ctypes`](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes#head-4ee0c35d45f89ef959a7d77b94c1c973101a562f) property of the arrays. It might take some work, so you might want to step back and see if there is a different way of solving your problem.