# Unexpected result with += on NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am creating symmetric matrices/arrays in Python with NumPy, using a standard method:

```
x = rand(500,500)
x = (x+x.T)
all(x==x.T)
> True
```

Now let's be clever:

```
x = rand(500,500)
x += x.T
all(x==x.T)
> False
```

Wait, what?

```
x==x.T
> array([[ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The upper left and lower right segments are symmetrical. What if I chose a smaller array?

```
x = rand(50,50)
x += x.T
all(x==x.T)
> True
```

OK....

```
x = rand(90,90)
x += x.T
all(x==x.T)
> True

x = rand(91,91)
x += x.T
all(x==x.T)
> False
```

And just to be sure...

```
x = rand(91,91)
x = (x+x.T)
all(x==x.T)
> True
```

Is this a bug, or am I about to learn something crazy about `+=` and NumPy arrays?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe this is Numpy 1.9 on Python 3.4.1, as distributed in Anaconda.

Comment: @jeffalstott yep, I misread the question -- I do see the behaviour too.

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524664/how-can-i-tell-if-numpy-creates-a-view-or-a-copy

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`transpose` operation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html) returns a *view* of the array, which means that no new array is allocated. Which, in turn, means that you are reading and modifying the array at the same time. It's hard to tell why some sizes or some areas of the result work, but most likely it has to do with how numpy deals with array addition (maybe it makes copies of submatrices) and/or array views (maybe for small sizes it does create a new array).

The `x = x + x.T` operation works because there you are creating a new array and then assigning to `x`, of course.

Answer (score 20):

The implementation detail mentioned by others is called **buffering**. You can read more about it in [the docs on array iteration](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#buffering-the-array-elements).

If you look at your failing example in a little more detail:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(91, 91)
>>> a += a.T
>>> a[:5, -1]
array([ 0.83818399,  1.06489316,  1.23675312,  0.00379798,  1.08967428])
>>> a[-1, :5]
array([ 0.83818399,  1.06489316,  1.75091827,  0.00416305,  1.76315071])
```

So the first wrong value is `90*91 + 2 = 8192`, which, unsurprisingly, is what we get from:

```
>>> np.getbufsize()
8192
```

And we can also set it higher, and then:

```
>>> np.setbufsize(16384)  # Must be a multiple of 16
8192  # returns the previous buffer size
>>> a = np.random.rand(91, 91)
>>> a += a.T
>>> np.all(a == a.T)
True
```

Although now:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(129, 129)
>>> a += a.T
>>> np.all(a == a.T)
False
```

This is of course a dangerous thing to rely on for correctness, as it is indeed an implementation detail subject to change.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the addition is not done "at once"; `x.T` is a *view* of the `x` so as you start adding to each element of `x`, `x.T` is mutated. This messes up later additions.

The fact it works for sizes below `(91, 91)` is almost definitely an implementation detail. Using

```
x = numpy.random.rand(1000, 1000)
x += x.T.copy()
numpy.all(x==x.T)
#>>> True
```

fixes that, but then you don't really have any space-benefit.