# OWNDATA flag unreliable in both directions for numpy arrays?

Tags: python, variables, numpy, memory

After reading the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524664/how-can-i-tell-if-numpy-creates-a-view-or-a-copy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886731/numpy-reshape-on-view), it seems that the `OWNDATA` flag isn't always reliable for numpy arrays in determining whether an object is a copy of another one or not.

The answers to these questions seem to say however that `OWNDATA` sometimes produces 'false negatives' (edit: on second thought, that might be more of a 'false positive') i.e. answers 'false' when in fact an object is a copy, and can be safely changed without changing the original.

Now I'm wondering: is the following a case of the flag also sometimes yielding false positives, i.e. claiming something is a copy, when it really isn't? (**Question, part 1**) Alternatively, I misunderstand what the `OWNDATA` flag is intended to tell me...

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = a
print(b.flags['OWNDATA']) # True

b = b+1
print(a==b) # False => b is copy, matching `OWNDATA` flag

b = a
print(b.flags['OWNDATA']) # True
b += 1
print(a==b) # True => b not a copy, mismatch with `OWNDATA`?
```

(**Question, part 2**) Finally: if neither `OWNDATA`, or `a.base is b` are reliable indicators to tell whether an object is a copy or not, then what what *is* the right to determine it? The questions linked above mention `may_share_memory`, but that one seems to be overeager in the other direction, answering 'True' on anything that is not constructed or created as a an explicit np.copy of another object.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  Something that you will test for in your code?  Or are you trying to learn which operations copy and which share?

Comment: @hpaulj A combination, I guess. I'd like to know if there is a general method to determine it, and, practically, I'd prefer not having to either (a) copy every time I'm unsure, (b) if I don't copy, test extensively, or (c) memorize which np operations copy or not under which exact conditions.

Comment: Looks like you already found my answer in the 2nd link.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I read it, but I'm not sure I understood if it also answers my question above (part 1). I think I get how `OWNDATA` can answer `False` in cases where it seems counterintuitive, but I don't understand how there can be a case of `OWNDATA` being `True` (like in my example) but the original array data changing nonetheless.

Comment: I think you are confusing share object references with shared data buffers.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking more at your example:

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = a
print(b.flags['OWNDATA']) # True
```

`b` is a reference to `a`; they are the same Python object

```
b = b+1
print(a==b) # False => b is copy, matching `OWNDATA` flag
```

`b` is now a new array, produced by the addition operation. It no longer points to the original array.  You could just as well looked a `c = b+1`, and tested `c`.  And it does not share the data buffer with the original `b`.

```
b = a
print(b.flags['OWNDATA']) # True
b += 1
print(a==b) # True => b not a copy, mismatch with `OWNDATA`?
```

`b` has been modified in-place; it's the same array object that is was before, but with new values.  Since `a` references the same object, it also 'appears' to be changed.  `b` is `a` and still has its own data buffer.  You might also look at the `id(b)`, and `id(a)`.

`OWNDATA` is meaningful only when comparing one array with a view or other operation - a different array object which may or may not share a data buffer with the original.

You may need to dig more into what `b=a` does in Python (it's not a numpy issue), and how arrays are constructed with data buffers.

Comment: "You may need to dig more into what b=a does in Python (it's not a numpy issue), and how arrays are constructed with data buffers." 
When writing my question I had the suspicion already I'm missing something more basic here... thanks a lot for taking the time to clear up my misunderstanding. Marking as answered.