# Multiplying every element of one array by every element of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, cartesian-product

Say I have two arrays,

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

What's the fastest, most Pythonic, etc., etc. way to get a new array, `z`, with a number of elements equal to `x.size * y.size`, in which the elements are the products of every pair of elements `(x_i, y_j)` from the two input arrays.

To rephrase, I'm looking for an array `z` in which `z[k]` is `x[i] * y[j]`.

A simple but inefficient way to get this is as follows:

```
z = np.empty(x.size * y.size)
counter = 0
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        z[counter] = i * j
        counter += 1
```

Running the above code shows that `z` in this example is

```
In [3]: z
Out[3]: 
array([  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,  10.,  12.,  14.,  16.,  15.,  18.,  21.,
        24.,  20.,  24.,  28.,  32.])
```

Comment: @dbliss: Could've been an outer product, could've been a convolution, could've been something else. Outer product looked most likely, but there wasn't enough information to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two more approaches could be suggested here.

Using [`matrix-multiplication with np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
np.dot(x[:,None],y[None]).ravel()
```

With [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('i,j->ij',x,y).ravel()
```

**Runtime tests**

```
In [31]: N = 10000
    ...: x = np.random.rand(N)
    ...: y = np.random.rand(N)
    ...: 

In [32]: %timeit np.dot(x[:,None],y[None]).ravel()
1 loops, best of 3: 302 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j->ij',x,y).ravel()
1 loops, best of 3: 274 ms per loop
```

Same as [`@BilalAkil's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30587209/3293881) but with `ravel()` instead of `flatten()` as a faster alternative -

```
In [34]: %timeit np.multiply.outer(x, y).ravel() 
1 loops, best of 3: 211 ms per loop
```

[`@BilalAkil's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30587209/3293881):

```
In [35]: %timeit np.multiply.outer(x, y).flatten()
1 loops, best of 3: 451 ms per loop
```

[`@Tim Leathart's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30587214/3293881):

```
In [36]: %timeit np.array([y * a for a in x]).flatten()
1 loops, best of 3: 766 ms per loop
```

Comment: odd that `ravel` is faster than `flatten`.  (i'd expect them to be the same.)  can you explain that time difference?

Comment: @dbliss It has to do with the fact that `flatten()` produces a copy, whereas `ravel()` is just a view into the input array, so it's *cheaper*. To verify this, you can create a toy setup : `A = np.random.rand(3,4)` and then check for view or not with `np.may_share_memory()`. So, `np.may_share_memory(A.ravel(),A)` would be `True`, whereas `np.may_share_memory(A.flatten(),A)` would result in `False`. More on checking view or not, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11524746/3293881

Answer (score 5):

Well I haven't much experience with numpy, but a quick search gave me this:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html

```
>>> np.multiply.outer([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
   [ 8, 10, 12],
   [12, 15, 18]])
```

You can then flatten that array to get the same output as you requested:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

EDIT: @Divakar's answer showed us that ravel will do the same thing as flatten, except faster o.O So use that instead.

So in your case, it'd look like this:

```
>>> np.multiply.outer(x, y).ravel()
```

BONUS: You can go multi-dimensional with this!

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import itertools


z = np.empty(x.size * y.size)
counter = 0
for i, j in itertools.product(x, y):
    z[counter] = i * j
    counter += 1
```

It'd be nice to get rid of that counter, though, as well as the `for` loop (but at least I got rid of one of the loops).

## **UPDATE**

Being one-liners, the other provided answers are better than this one (according to my standards, which value brevity).  The timing results below show that @BilalAkil's answer is faster than @TimLeathart's:

```
In [10]: %timeit np.array([x * j for j in y]).flatten()
The slowest run took 4.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.2 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit np.multiply.outer(x, y).flatten()
The slowest run took 5.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Although you got rid of one of the loops, you're still performing a cross multiplication (in this case with `itertools.product`), so it's still got the same complexity as having both loops: O(xy). It'll be difficult to avoid that.

Comment: Try timing your basic loop implementations too. The one with your nested loops and the `itertools.product` one :P

Comment: @BilalAkil i'd rather not embarrass myself ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
z = np.array([y * a for a in x]).flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm super late to the party here, but I thought I'd throw my hat into the ring for anyone reading this question in the future. Using the same metric as @Divakar, I added what I consider to be a much more intuitive solution to the list (the first code snippet measured):

```
import numpy as np
N = 10000
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

%timeit np.ravel(x[:,None] * y[None])
635 ms ± 19.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.outer(x, y).ravel()
640 ms ± 16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.dot(x[:,None],y[None]).ravel()
853 ms ± 57.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.einsum('i,j->ij',x,y).ravel()
754 ms ± 19.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Based on the similarity in execution time, it seems likely that `numpy.outer` functions exactly the same way as my solution internally, although you should take observations like this with a hefty grain of salt.

The reason why I find it more intuitive is that, unlike all other solutions, its syntax isn't strictly limited to multiplication. For example, `np.ravel(x[:,None] / y[None])` will give you a / b for every a in x and b in y.