# How do you multiply each number in a list with each number in another list

Tags: list

I have two lists:

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

I want to multiply each number in the first list with each number in the second list to get the result:

list3 = [4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18]

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587076/multiplying-every-element-of-one-array-by-every-element-of-another-array

Comment: I tried using zip but only multiplied each element in the first list with one corresponding element in the second list.

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-multiply-two-lists-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplying every element of one array by every element of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587076/multiplying-every-element-of-one-array-by-every-element-of-another-array)

Answer (score 0):

> There could be a more pythonic way to do this but this gets the job
> done.

```
lst1 = [1,2,3]
lst2 = [4,5,6]
lst3 = []
for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
        lst3.append(i*j)
print(lst3)
```

**Using list comprehension:**

```
print([(l1*l2) for l1 in lst1 for l2 in lst2])
```