# Flattening a list of NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

It appears that I have data in the format of a list of NumPy arrays (`type() = np.ndarray`):

```
[array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), 
array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), 
array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), 
array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]), array([[ 0.00353654]]),
array([[ 0.00353654]])]
```

I am trying to put this into a polyfit function:

```
m1 = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=2)
```

However, it returns the error: `TypeError: expected 1D vector for x`

I assume I need to flatten my data into something like:

```
[0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654 ...]
```

I have tried a list comprehension which usually works on lists of lists, but this as expected has not worked:

```
[val for sublist in risks for val in sublist]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! Works for me!

Comment: concatenate assumes that all the arrays are the same size, which may always be the case for you, otherwise check out something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/406822/1240268.

Comment: Do the arrays all have the same length?

Comment: Not sure if duplicate but definitely related https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930465/4755520.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), which as the name suggests, basically concatenates all the elements of such an input list into a single NumPy array, like so -

```
import numpy as np
out = np.concatenate(input_list).ravel()
```

If you wish the final output to be a list, you can extend the solution, like so -

```
out = np.concatenate(input_list).ravel().tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [24]: input_list
Out[24]: 
[array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]])]

In [25]: np.concatenate(input_list).ravel()
Out[25]: 
array([ 0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,
        0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,
        0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654])
```

Convert to list -

```
In [26]: np.concatenate(input_list).ravel().tolist()
Out[26]: 
[0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654,
 0.00353654]
```

Comment: by doing so, I get `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Comment: @Athena Post a new question please. It's not clear what exactly is the data format.

Comment: @Athena I think I had the same issue: it's because the arrays in the list have different shapes. I was able to get a flattened array using: `np.concatenate(input_list, axis=None).ravel()`

Answer (score 19):

Can also be done by

```
np.array(list_of_arrays).flatten().tolist()
```

resulting in

```
[0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654]
```

---

**Update**

As @aydow points out in the comments, using `numpy.ndarray.ravel` can be faster if one doesn't care about getting a [copy or a view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11524664/4755520)

```
np.array(list_of_arrays).ravel()
```

Although, according to [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

> When a view is desired in as many cases as possible, `arr.reshape(-1)` may be preferable.

In other words

```
np.array(list_of_arrays).reshape(-1)
```

The **initial suggestion** of mine was to use `numpy.ndarray.flatten` that [returns a copy every time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930580/4755520) which affects performance.

Let's now see how the **time complexity** of the above-listed solutions compares using [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) package for a setup similar to the one of the OP

```
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n, 2),
    kernels=[lambda a: a.ravel(),
             lambda a: a.flatten(),
             lambda a: a.reshape(-1)],
    labels=['ravel', 'flatten', 'reshape'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(16)],
    xlabel='N')
```

[image]

Here `flatten` demonstrates piecewise linear complexity which can be reasonably explained by it making a copy of the initial array compare to constant complexities of `ravel` and `reshape` that return a view.

It's also worth noting that, quite predictably, converting the outputs `.tolist()` evens out the performance of all three to equally linear.

Comment: `np.flatten` works, but it's worth noting that it's significantly slower than `np.ravel`. this difference gets worse as the `array` length increases

Comment: @aydow hmm, how so? `np.flatten` is indeed slower but not significantly. I just `%%timeit` both on `list(map(np.array, np.random.rand(1_000_000, 10)))` and `np.concatenate(list_of_arrays).ravel()` takes `290 ms ± 2.49 ms` against `np.array(list_of_arrays).flatten()`'s `446 ms ± 26.5 ms` with both performing seemingly instantaneously without `%%timeit` on my laptop.

Comment: hi @ayorgo, i'm deviating slightly from the OP question. i'm assuming an `np.array` of `np.array`s (which pertained to my own question) rather than a `list` of `np.array`s. using just `np.ravel` takes `249 ns ± 8.43 ns` while using just `np.flatten` takes `25.4 ms ± 244 µs`!! adding `np.concatenate` and `np.array` slows it down to the numbers you've mentioned. apologies for not specifying this in my initial comment

Comment: @aydow haha, indeed! What I believe makes such a difference in performance is that `np.flatten` always returns a copy unlike 'np.ravel' (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930580/4755520). The interesting thing also is that the accepted answer doesn't need to use `np.concatenate`. Simply converting to `np.array` and `.ravel()` would suffice.

Answer (score 6):

Another way using `itertools` for flattening the array:

```
import itertools

# Recreating array from question
a = [np.array([[0.00353654]])] * 13

# Make an iterator to yield items of the flattened list and create a list from that iterator
flattened = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
```

This solution should be very **fast**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/408281/5993892 for more explanation.

If the resulting data structure should be a `numpy` array instead, use `numpy.fromiter()` to exhaust the iterator into an array:

```
# Make an iterator to yield items of the flattened list and create a numpy array from that iterator
flattened_array = np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a), float)
```

**Docs for `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:** 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

**Docs for `numpy.fromiter()`:** 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html

Answer (score 5):

Another simple approach would be to use [**`numpy.hstack()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) followed by removing the singleton dimension using `squeeze()` as in:

```
In [61]: np.hstack(list_of_arrs).squeeze()
Out[61]: 
array([0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654,
       0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654,
       0.00353654, 0.00353654, 0.00353654])
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this same issue and found a solution that combines 1-D numpy arrays of variable length:

```
np.column_stack(input_list).ravel()
```

See [numpy.column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) for more info.

Example with variable-length arrays with your example data:

```
In [135]: input_list
Out[135]: 
[array([[ 0.00353654,  0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654]]),
 array([[ 0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654]])]

In [136]: [i.size for i in input_list]    # variable size arrays
Out[136]: [2, 1, 1, 3]

In [137]: np.column_stack(input_list).ravel()
Out[137]: 
array([ 0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,  0.00353654,
        0.00353654,  0.00353654])
```

Note: Only tested on Python 2.7.12

Comment: I tried this and got `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly` :(

Comment: I was able to make it work using `np.hstack` instead of `np.column_stack`. I think this is because my arrays are 1d, and I didn't read the original question carefully enough. Thanks anyway :)