# Get DataFrame column value as array with target dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the column values from DataFrame, which consists of arrays. By using `DataFrame.values`, the returned `dtype` is object, what I want is `float64`.

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'vector':[np.array([1.1,2,3]),np.array([2.1,3,4])]})
print(a)

b=a['vector'].values
print(b.dtype)
print(b.shape)

c=np.array([i for i in  a['vector']])
print(c.dtype)
print(c.shape)

>>>             vector
>>> 0  [1.1, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> 1  [2.1, 3.0, 4.0]
>>> object
>>> (2,)
>>> float64
>>> (2, 3)
```

why b and c has different `dtype`?

`c` is what I want to get, but is there any better way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `Series` to list and then pass it to np.array i.e

```
np.array(a['vector'].tolist())

array([[ 1.1,  2. ,  3. ],
   [ 2.1,  3. ,  4. ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33718947/2251785,

[`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) should works too.

```
d=np.concatenate(a['vector'].values).reshape(len(a),-1)
```

Still confused about why `.values` treats `array` as `object`...