# Flatten a list containing numpy arrays with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find a solution for flattening the following lists of numpy arrays:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
b = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
c = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
myarrs = [a,b,c]

d = np.arange(5*5*5).reshape(5,5,5)
myarrs2 = [a,b,c,d]
```

For my `myarrs` I am using at the moment:

```
res = np.hstack([np.hstack(i) for i in myarrs])
```

But I was wondering if there are any other built-in methods for performing this task in particular in case of arrays with different shapes.
I saw the other questions:  [Flattening a list of NumPy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711985/flattening-a-list-of-numpy-arrays) but they usually refer to arrays with the same shape.

Comment: Use `np.hstack([i.ravel() for i in myarrs2])` for a more efficient one. That ravel is a view, hence better than the inner hstack that you have. But no builtin yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])
```

This should be faster than your approach:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
b = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
c = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
myarrs = [a,b,c]


res = np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])
print(res)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24  0  1  2  3]


%timeit np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.47 µs per loop
%timeit np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: x.ravel(), myarrs)))
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.85 µs per loop
%timeit np.concatenate([x.flatten() for x in myarrs])
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.69 µs per loop
%timeit np.hstack([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.69 µs per loop
%timeit np.hstack([np.hstack(i) for i in myarrs])
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are looking for `numpy` only solution. However, if allowed, one more possibility is to use `more_itertools` together with [`ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`reshape(-1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) or [`flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
>>> import more_itertools
>>> list(more_itertools.flatten(([x.reshape(-1) for x in myarrs])))
```

#### Comparision:

**Original solution**

```
%timeit -n 100000 np.hstack([np.hstack(i) for i in myarrs])
> 31.6 µs ± 1.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Solution from [norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218354/norok2) (fastest)**

```
%timeit -n 100000 np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])
> 2.62 µs ± 54.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Solution with `more_itertools` + `reshape(-1)`**

```
%timeit -n 100000 list(more_itertools.flatten(([x.reshape(-1) for x in myarrs])))
> 9.32 µs ± 255 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Solution with `more_itertools` + `ravel()`**

```
%timeit -n 100000 list(more_itertools.flatten(([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])))
> 7.33 µs ± 235 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Solution with `more_itertools` + `flatten()`**

```
%timeit list(more_itertools.flatten(([x.flatten() for x in myarrs])))
> 8.3 µs ± 65.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: `'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'`

Comment: @seralouk Can I get negative upvote removed now, please?

Comment: Thanks. I will be more careful while writing my first answer.

Comment: how would this compare to `np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in myarrs])`?

Comment: What do you mean? Your `np.concatenate`  solution is the fastest.

Comment: @Grayrigel it would be interesting to see the number you get on the same platform you got your `more_itertools`-based solution benchmarks.