# Concatenate several arrays withon one array into one array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that consists of more then 2000 arrays inside and looks like this:

```
array([[0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.9679647e+14, ..., 1.6781340e+13,
    1.0186320e+13, 4.1649500e+12],
   [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4426557e+14, ..., 1.2301900e+13,
    7.4672900e+12, 3.0532000e+12],
   [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4426557e+14, ..., 1.2301900e+13,
    7.4672900e+12, 3.0532000e+12],
   ...,
   [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4426557e+14, ..., 1.2301900e+13,
    7.4672900e+12, 3.0532000e+12],
   [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4426557e+14, ..., 1.2301900e+13,
    7.4672900e+12, 3.0532000e+12],
   [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 3.9105554e+14, ..., 3.3346310e+13,
    2.0241300e+13, 8.2762000e+12]])
```

I need to concatenate these arrays into one big array so I will have one array only without array of arrays and look like this:

```
[ 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.9679647e+14, ..., 1.6781340e+13,1.0186320e+13, 4.1649500e+12, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4426557e+14, ..., 1.2301900e+13,7.4672900e+12, 3.0532000e+12, ...,0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 3.9105554e+14, ..., 3.3346310e+13,
    2.0241300e+13, 8.2762000e+12]
```

Is it any way to do this?

Comment: Just call `flatten()`

Comment: What's the array `shape` and `dtype`?  If you don't know what those are, you haven't read enough of numpy beginner's intro.

Comment: thank you, just started to learning how to work with numpy arrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flattening a list of NumPy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711985/flattening-a-list-of-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
flat_array = messy_numpy_array.flatten()
```