# Precision,recall, F1 score with Sklearn on Pytorch

Tags: scikit-learn, pytorch, precision-recall

I've been looking through samples but am unable to understand how to integrate the precision, recall and f1 metrics for my model. My code is as follows:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):

#Calculate Accuracy (stack tutorial no n_total)
n_correct = 0
n_total = 0

for i, (words, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
    words = words.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(dtype=torch.long).to(device)
    
    # Forward pass
    outputs = model(words)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    
    # Backward and optimize
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    #feedforward tutorial solution
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
    n_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    n_total += labels.shape[0]

accuracy = 100 * n_correct/n_total

#Push to matplotlib
train_losses.append(loss.item())
train_epochs.append(epoch)
train_acc.append(accuracy)

#Loss and Accuracy
if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.2f}, Acc: {accuracy:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the `predicted` and the `labels` variables, you can aggregate them during the epoch loop and convert them to numpy arrays to calculate the required metrics.

At the beginning of the epoch, initialize two empty lists; one for true labels and one for ground truth labels.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    predicted_labels, ground_truth_labels = [], []
    ...
```

Then, keep appending the respective entries to each list during the epoch:

```
   ...
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
    n_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    
    # appending
    predicted_labels.append(predicted.cpu().detach().numpy())
    ground_truth_labels.append(labels.cpu().detach().numpy())

...
```

Then, at the epoch end, you could use [`precision_recall_fscore_support`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) with `predicted_labels` and `ground_truth_labels` as inputs.

Notes:

1. You'll probably have to refer something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711985/flattening-a-list-of-numpy-arrays) to flatten the above two lists.
2. Read about [`torch.no_grad()`](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/what-is-the-use-of-torch-no-grad-in-pytorch) to apply it as a good practice during the calculations of metrics.