# Repeating numpy values and specifying dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to generate a numpy array of the form:

```
0.5*[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], ...]
```

I want the final array to have a `dtype` of `numpy.float32`.

Here is my attempt:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 5
>>> x = np.array(np.repeat(0.5*np.arange(N), 2), np.float32)
>>> x
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1.5,  1.5,  2. ,  2. ], dtype=float32)
```

Is this a good way? Can I avoid the copy (if it is indeed copying) just for type conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only has to reshape your final result to obtain what you want:

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 2)
```

You could also run `arange` passing the `dtype`:

```
x = np.repeat(0.5*np.arange(N, dtype=np.float32), 2).reshape(-1, 2)
```

You can easily cast the array as another type using the `astype` method, which accepts an argument `copy`:

```
x.astype(np.int8, copy=False)
```

But, [as explained in the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), `numpy` checks for some requirements in order to return the view. If those requirements are not satisfied, a copy is returned.

You can check if a given array is a copy or a view from another by checking the `OWNDATA` attribute, accessible through the `flags` property of the `ndarray`.

---

EDIT: more on checking if a given array is a copy...

- [Is there a way to check if numpy arrays share the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11286864/832621)

Comment: checking for view/copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286864/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-numpy-arrays-share-the-same-data

Comment: You could also change `0.5*np.arange(N, dtype=np.float32)` to `np.arange(0, 0.5*N, 0.5, dtype=np.float32)` to avoid a temporary array.

Comment: Using arange with a non-exact data type is generally not good (it is just prone to floating point inaccuracies). It is probably better multiply by 0.5 afterwards. There are probably very few cases where this kind of thing is speed relevant anyway.

Comment: @seberg: That's generally good advice. In most cases I use `np.linspace` for exactly that reason.  In this case, however, `N` is an integer, so `0.5*N` is exact (unless `N` is huge), and `arange` is fine.  (I also agree that avoiding the temporary is a micro-optimization and not too important.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
 np.array([0.5*np.arange(N, dtype=np.float32)]*2)
```

Gives:

```
array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ]], dtype=float32)
```

You might want to rotate it:

```
np.rot90(np.array([0.5*np.arange(N, dtype=np.float32)]*2),3)
```

Giving:

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.5,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  2. ]], dtype=float32)
```

Note, this is slower than @Saullo_Castro's answer:

```
np.rot90(np.array([0.5*np.arange(N, dtype=np.float32)]*2),3)

10000 loops, best of 3: 24.3us per loop

np.repeat(0.5*np.arange(N, dtype=np.float32), 2).reshape(-1, 2)

10000 loops, best of 3: 9.23 us per loop

np.array(np.repeat(0.5*np.arange(N), 2), np.float32).reshape(-1, 2)

10000 loops, best of 3: 10.4 us per loop
```

(using `%%timeit` on ipython)