# how to use abbrevation of the dtype?

Tags: numpy

I cannot find any documents about the abbreviation of the dtypes. Such as `<i8`, `f2`, etc. Can anyone point me a direction?

How to represent `bool8` in that form?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeating numpy values and specifying dtype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812717/repeating-numpy-values-and-specifying-dtype)