# Howto convert numpy 1D-array to congiuous 2D-column-array without copying the data

Tags: arrays, numpy

Is it possible to convert a one dimensional array

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

to a two dimensional array that is equivalent to

```
b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
```

1. without creating a copy of the array and also
2. with `b` being contiguous?

Comment: What do you mean by "without creating a copy of the data?"

Comment: @Ffisegydd I do not want the data to be copied in memory. Rather I want numpy to use the same memory but interpret it differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and the [`T` transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) method.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])

a = a[np.newaxis].T

print(a)
# [[1]
#  [2]
#  [3]]
```

Comment: If I run this code, `a` is not contiguous and it also appears that the data is copied...

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping the array does not copy data (where possible*) and retains C contiguity (usually):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = a.reshape(3, 1)
>>> b
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

>>> b.flags

  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

***Edit:** Reshaping often creates a view of an array, but this is not *always* possible ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)). There are ways to check that the data has not been copied and that `a` and `b` share the same underlying data. For example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286864/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-numpy-arrays-share-the-same-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524664/how-can-i-tell-if-numpy-creates-a-view-or-a-copy).

In the above case, trying a couple of tests showed that `reshape` created a view of `a` (no data copied):

```
>>> a.data == b.data
True

>>> np.may_share_memory(a, b) # function from linked answer above
True
```

Comment: I though about this very same solution. How do you know that the data is not copied? Doesn't `id(a) != id(b)` prove that the data is copied?

Comment: @Woltan updated my answer slightly. Sharing data between arrays is not always easy to determine (the `id` test isn't reliable because of the fundamental differences between Python and NumPy objects).