# Using a stored value of a variable in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The given code below is a part of a code i am working on. Here `x` is a numpy array and f is an array of arrays as given in the example below the code. i have to update all values of the array `x` and thus i use run a loop to do so. I am using an iterative scheme and the values are updated using the last known value of `x`. However the loop runs fine for the first time, but the next time it takes the value of `x` that it got when the 1st loop was run. But i intend to take the old value of `x` for all the loops. Can anyone help me out please?

```
import numpy as np
def mulsucc(x0,f,n):
    old=x0
    for k in range(1,100):
        for i in range(0,n):
            print "old" + str(old)
            x0[i]=np.sum(old*(f[i][0:len(f[i])-1])) + 2
            print "new" + str(x0)
        return x0
x0=np.array([0,0])
f=np.array([[4,5,-20],[2,7,-10]])
print mulsucc(x0,f,2)
```

the output comes out to be:

```
old[0 0]
new[2 0]
old[2 0]
new[2 6]
[2 6]
```

however I want that the second old value should also be `[0 0]`.

Comment: The `k` loop is not "used" since you do a return after the `i` loop. Is that on purpose?

Comment: It is a part of a bigger code.. so actually i forgot to remove the k loop.. the problem i face is currently only concerned with the i loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change:

```
old = x0
```

to:

```
old = x0.copy()
```

if you want to keep `old` unchanged. The problem here is that `old` and `x0` are pointers to the same object, so when you alter `x0` with the line:

```
x0[i]=np.sum(old*(f[i][0:len(f[i])-1])) + 2
```

you are also altering `old`. `old is x0` will be `True`.
There is more to it if you want to dig a bit into related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286864/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-numpy-arrays-share-the-same-data).