# Why would NumPy reshape() create a new array and why might order not be preserved?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

There are a few questions on SO about checking whether the `numpy.reshape` call has returned a copy or not [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524664/how-can-i-tell-if-numpy-creates-a-view-or-a-copy), [2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286864/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-numpy-arrays-share-the-same-data). These questions are generally posed due to the vague warning from the doc that:

> This will be a new view object if possible; otherwise, it will be a copy.

What I'm wondering is in what circumstances will NumPy return a copy? In every 2D `reshape` call I've tested, the method from user jterrace's answer in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286864/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-numpy-arrays-share-the-same-data) shows that the memory base is the same (i.e. not a copy). Is it only for higher dimensional `reshape` that a copy may be necessary?

Additionally, the second part of the warning from the docs informs the user that:

> ...there is no guarantee of the memory layout (C- or Fortran- contiguous) of the returned array.

In other words, you may ask for row-major, but you could get column-major output. Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of the `order` parameter? When would this case arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm wondering is in what circumstances will NumPy return a copy?

```
In [13]: x = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],
   ....:                  [4, 5, 6]])

In [14]: x[:, :2].reshape([4]).base is x
Out[14]: False
```

If the strides don't work for the new shape, NumPy has to copy.

> In other words, you may ask for row-major, but you could get column-major output. Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of the `order` parameter?

No. `numpy.reshape` provides no way to ask for a specific memory layout. The `order` parameter specifies what index order to read elements in; it has nothing to do with memory layout.

Comment: In other words, in order to get the desired *memory layout*, one would need to explicitly write it to a copy in memory?

Comment: To elaborate, that last reshape produces `array([1, 2, 4, 5])`, a subset of the original `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: Okay. So am I to also understand that the only time a copy arises is when not all of the original data is retained through the reshape? As in this stride example

Comment: For the same `x`, `x.T.reshape(2,3)` is a copy.  All the data is there, but it's in a different raveled order.

Comment: @marcman: No, that has nothing to do with it. A copy arises when the elements of the resulting array wouldn't have a consistent stride in memory along each axis for a view.