# What is the difference between numpy.shares_memory and numpy.may_share_memory?

Tags: python, numpy

Why does `numpy.may_share_memory` exist?
What is the challenge to give an exact result?

Is `numpy.may_share_memory` deprecated method?
`numpy.may_share_memory` may give false positives, but it does not give false negatives.

Does `numpy.shares_memory` give no one false positive and no one false negative?

I use numpy version `1.11.2`.

See:

1. [numpy.may_share_memory](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html#numpy.may_share_memory)
2. [numpy.shares_memory](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy.shares_memory)
3. [version 1.11.2 source on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/v1.11.2)

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish between views and copies,or between possibly overlapping fancy indexings?

Comment: @hpaulj Of course yes ;). But I studied the issue, and now I understoodd that the memory overlap detection is not very easy to have good performance. I am writing a complete answer to this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting the [release notes for 1.11.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/release.html#new-features):

> A new function `np.shares_memory` that can check exactly whether two arrays have memory overlap is added. `np.may_share_memory` also now has an option to spend more effort to reduce false positives.

Semantically, this suggests that the older `may_share_memory` test was designed to get a loose guess whether memory is shared between the arrays. If surely not, then one could proceed accordingly. If there was a positive test (possibly a false positive), care had to be taken. The new `shares_memory` function, on the other hand, allows exact checks. This takes more computational time, but can be beneficial in the long run, since free of false positives one can use more possible optimizations. The looser check of `may_share_memory` probably only guarantees to not return false *negatives*.

In terms of the documentation of [`may_share_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html#numpy.may_share_memory) and [`shares_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy.shares_memory), both have a keyword argument that tells numpy how strict a check the user wants.

`may_share_memory`:

```
max_work : int, optional

    Effort to spend on solving the overlap problem. See shares_memory for details. Default for may_share_memory is to do a bounds check.
```

`shares_memory`:

```
max_work : int, optional

    Effort to spend on solving the overlap problem (maximum number of candidate solutions to consider). The following special values are recognized:

    max_work=MAY_SHARE_EXACT (default)

        The problem is solved exactly. In this case, the function returns True only if there is an element shared between the arrays.
    max_work=MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS

        Only the memory bounds of a and b are checked.
```

Judging by the docs, this suggests that the two functions might call the same underlying machinery, but `may_share_memory` uses a less strict default setting for the check.

Let's take a peek [at the implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L3940-L4071):

```c
static PyObject *
array_shares_memory(PyObject *NPY_UNUSED(ignored), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    return array_shares_memory_impl(args, kwds, NPY_MAY_SHARE_EXACT, 1);
}


static PyObject *
array_may_share_memory(PyObject *NPY_UNUSED(ignored), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    return array_shares_memory_impl(args, kwds, NPY_MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS, 0);
}
```

calling the same underlying function with signature

```c
static PyObject *
array_shares_memory_impl(PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds, Py_ssize_t default_max_work,
                         int raise_exceptions)
{}
```

Without delving deeper into the source, it seems to me that `shares_memory` is an improvement over `may_share_memory`, which can give the same loose check as the latter with the appropriate keyword arguments. The older function can be used for convenience and backward compatibility.

Disclaimer: this is the first time I looked at this part of the source, and I didn't investigate further into `array_shares_memory_impl`, so my impression can be simply wrong.

---

As for a specific example for the difference between the two methods (called with default arguments): it is explained at the above links that `may_share_memory` only checks array bound indices. If they are disjoint for the two arrays, then there's *no chance* that they can share memory. But if they are *not* disjoint, the arrays can still be independent!

Simple example: a disjoint partitioning of a contiguous block of memory via slicing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = np.arange(6)
>>> x = v[::2]
>>> y = v[1::2]
>>> np.may_share_memory(x,y)
True
>>> np.shares_memory(x,y)
False
>>> np.may_share_memory(x,y,max_work=np.MAY_SHARE_EXACT)
False
```

As you can see, `x` and `y` are two disjoint slices of the same array. Thus their data ranges largely overlap (they are almost the same, save a single integer in memory). However, none of their elements are actually the same: one contains the even, the other the odd elements of the original contiguous block. So `may_share_memory` correctly asserts that the arrays *may* share memory, but on a stricter check it turns out that they don't.

---

As for the additional difficulty of computing the overlap exactly, the work can be traced down to the worker called [`solve_may_share_memory`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/private/mem_overlap.c#L754), which also contains a lot of helpful comments about what's going on. In a nutshell, there's

1. [`a quick check and return`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/private/mem_overlap.c#L763-L769) if the bounds *don't* overlap, otherwise
2. a [return with `MEM_OVERLAP_TOO_HARD`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/private/mem_overlap.c#L771-L774) if we asked for loose checking (i.e. `may_share_memory` with default args), which is [handled on the calling side](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4027-L4030) as "we don't know, so return `True`"
3. otherwise we actually solve the Diophantine equations that the problem maps to [starting here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/private/mem_overlap.c#L776)

So the work in point 3 above is what needs to additionally be done by `shares_memory` (or generally, a strict checking case).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I upvoted. But it remains a subquestion, why is  it complicated to check to say if two arrays share memory? Why have numpy developers not written `shares_memory` directly? What was the challenge?

Comment: Good example. Note: `np.shares_memory(x, y, max_work=np.MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS)` raises `TooHardError: Exceeded max_work` also? But I think, I am going to read the source code to understand the challenge to implement `shares_memory` directly.

Comment: @glegoux I just investigated that too (well, some of it), please see my links to spare some work for yourself, digging in the source :)

Comment: I am so curious you know, I completed your answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Before reading the following, read :

http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html
http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/

In fact the problem is to find memory overlap for two strided arrays `a` and `b`:

See [Implementatation NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/src/private/mem_overlap.c) (It is important to read the comment in the header).

This problem is equivalent to :

*"Find solution to a bounded Diophantine equations with positive coefficients"*

Take an example for 1D-array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(8, dtype=np.int8)
a = x[::3]
b = x[1::2]
```

In memory we have:

[image: 1D array]

1D array is a contiguous structure in memory. I suppose that our memory has 64 bits addresses (on 8 bytes), and each element our array has a size of one byte (0 <= np.int8 < 256).

To resolve the overlap issue, the possible memory addresses of one element of `a` are :

`base_a + stride_a * x_a` where `x_a` is a variable (array index 0-based).

And we have the same for `b` :

`base_b + stride_b * x_b` where `x_b` is a variable (array index 0-based).

There is overlap if and only if :

`base_a + stride_a * x_a = base_b + stride_b * x_b`

We have :

`stride_a * x_a - stride_b * x_b = base_b - base_a`

with `0 <= x_a < shape_a` and `0 <= x_b < shape_b`.

We can transform all negative coefficients, instead of reading `b`
top to bottom, we can read that from bottom to top by a variable change :

`x_b' = shape_b - 1 - x_b`

We obtain:

`stride_a * x_a + stride_b * x_b = base_b  + stride_b * (shape_b - 1) - base_a`

Here :

`3 x_a + 2 x_b = 7 (= 1 + 2 * (4 - 1))`

with `0 <= x_a < 3` and `0 <= x_b < 4`.

One solution is `x_a = 1` and `x_b = 2` (read from bottom for `x_b`).

....

We can easily generalize that for 2D array then XD array, and of each array element takes more than one byte (for example 4 bytes, all array elements are necessary a common size in memory).

Here a [naive solution on my github and comparaison performance with NumPy implementation](https://github.com/glegoux/memory_overlap/tree/master).

...