# How to find out `DataFrame.to_numpy` did not create a copy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The [`pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) method has a `copy` argument with the following documentation:

> **copy : *bool, default False***
>
> Whether to ensure that the returned value is a not a view on another array. Note that copy=False does not ensure that to_numpy() is no-copy. Rather, copy=True ensure that a copy is made, even if not strictly necessary.

Playing around a bit, it seems like calling `to_numpy` on data that is both adjacent in memory and not of mixed types, keeps a view. But **how do I check whether the resulting numpy array shares the memory with the data frame it was created from, without changing data?**

Example of memory sharing:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some data frame that I expect not to be copied
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(144).reshape(12,12))
array = frame.to_numpy()
array[:] = 0
print(frame)
# Prints:
#     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
# 0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 5   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 7   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
# 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
```

Example not sharing memory:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some data frame that I expect to be copied
types = [int, str, float]
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    i: [types[i%len(types)](value) for value in col]
    for i, col in enumerate(np.arange(144).reshape(12,12).T)
})
array = frame.to_numpy()
array[:] = 0
print(frame)
# Prints:
#     0   1     2   3   4     5   6   7      8    9    10     11
# 0    0  12  24.0  36  48  60.0  72  84   96.0  108  120  132.0
# 1    1  13  25.0  37  49  61.0  73  85   97.0  109  121  133.0
# 2    2  14  26.0  38  50  62.0  74  86   98.0  110  122  134.0
# 3    3  15  27.0  39  51  63.0  75  87   99.0  111  123  135.0
# 4    4  16  28.0  40  52  64.0  76  88  100.0  112  124  136.0
# 5    5  17  29.0  41  53  65.0  77  89  101.0  113  125  137.0
# 6    6  18  30.0  42  54  66.0  78  90  102.0  114  126  138.0
# 7    7  19  31.0  43  55  67.0  79  91  103.0  115  127  139.0
# 8    8  20  32.0  44  56  68.0  80  92  104.0  116  128  140.0
# 9    9  21  33.0  45  57  69.0  81  93  105.0  117  129  141.0
# 10  10  22  34.0  46  58  70.0  82  94  106.0  118  130  142.0
# 11  11  23  35.0  47  59  71.0  83  95  107.0  119  131  143.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [numpy.shares_memory](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy.shares_memory) you can use:

```py
# Your first example
print(np.shares_memory(array, frame))  # True, they are sharing memory

# Your second example
print(np.shares_memory(array2, frame2))  # False, they are not sharing memory
```

There is also [numpy.may_share_memory](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html), which is faster but can only be used for making sure things do *not* share memory (because it only checks whether the bounds overlap), so strictly speaking does not answer the question.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865261/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-shares-memory-and-numpy-may-share-memory) for the differences.

Take care using these numpy functions with pandas data-structures:
`np.shares_memory(frame, frame)` returns `True` for the first example, **but `False` for the second**, probably because the `__array__` method of the data frame in the second example creates a copy behind the scenes.

Comment: I would use `np.shares_memory`. It's not as fast, but `np.may_share_memory` is like the `copy` argument in that it can guaranty that two arrays do _not_ share data, but can only hint at whether they do.

Answer (score 1):

In your first case you make the frame from an array.  The source array is used 'as-is' as the data for the frame. That is, the frame just adds its indices and methods to the original array:

```
In [377]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                    
In [378]: df = pd.DataFrame(arr)                                                              
In [379]: df                                                                                  
Out[379]: 
   0  1   2   3
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
In [380]: arr1 = df.to_numpy()                                                                
In [381]: arr1                                                                                
Out[381]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

I like to compare arrays with the `array_interface` dictionary.  Note that the `data` is identical in both:

```
In [382]: arr.__array_interface__                                                             
Out[382]: 
{'data': (53291792, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 4),
 'version': 3}
In [383]: arr1.__array_interface__                                                            
Out[383]: 
{'data': (53291792, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 4),
 'version': 3}
```

I could do the mutation test as well.

In the second case you make the frame from a dictionary.  I suspect in this case the frame is actually a collection of `pd.Series`, though I'm not sure how to test that.

```
In [393]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(3), 'b':np.ones(3)})                              
In [394]: df1                                                                                 
Out[394]: 
   a    b
0  0  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  2  1.0
In [395]: x = df1.to_numpy()                                                                  
In [396]: x                                                                                   
Out[396]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [2., 1.]])
```

The change in `dtypes` is good indication that `x` is a copy.  Columns of `df1` differ in dtype, while `x` is all float.

And with the mutating test:

```
In [397]: x *= 0                                                                              
In [398]: df1                                                                                 
Out[398]: 
   a    b
0  0  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  2  1.0
```

on the other hand, constructing the same frame but with all floats, the array isn't a copy:

```
In [399]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(3.), 'b':np.ones(3)})                             
In [400]: df1                                                                                 
Out[400]: 
     a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0
In [401]: x = df1.to_numpy()                                                                  
In [402]: x *= 0                                                                              
In [403]: df1                                                                                 
Out[403]: 
     a    b
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0
```

Others have suggested looking at the flags.  I'm not sure that's reliable.  I checked the [396] case, and `x` did  not `owndata`.

I probably haven't added much to your observations.  I think we need to dig more into how a frame stores its data.  That may depend, not only on how the frame was constructed, but also on how it was modified (for example, what happens when I add a column?).

`df.to_numpy` is just `np.array(self.values, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)`.  At this level, whether it's a copy or not depends on the `dtype` conversion, if any.

`df.values` is a property that does:

```
self._consolidate_inplace()
return self._data.as_array(transpose=self._AXIS_REVERSED)
```

`df._data` is a `BlockManager` (at least in my examples)

If this is a `single_block`, its `as_array` does

```
np.asarray(mgr.blocks[0].get_values())
```

I was going to show the BlockMangers for the different dataframes, but just lost that interactive Ipython session.

The [379] frame has just one integer block; the [394] frame has two, one float, one integer.

In any case, there's a lot of pandas code behind the `to_numpy()` method.  And much of it depends on exactly how the data is stored for that frame.  So I don't think there's a simple surefire way of identifying whether an array is a copy or not.  Except in simple, uniform dataframe cases, it's better to assume it's a copy.  But be wary of modifying the array if you don't want to modify the frame.

Use `df.to_numpy(copy=True)` to be sure that you get a copy.

I don't think you can be sure about getting a view.  If the df has a uniform, matching dtype, there's a good chance it's a view, especially if the construction wasn't too convoluted.

====

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3,4),int))                                                                   
In [3]: df                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
In [4]: df.to_numpy().flags                                                                                     
Out[4]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False              <====
  ...
In [5]: df.to_numpy(copy=True).flags                                                                            
Out[5]: 
  ...
  OWNDATA : True
```

Now a frame with mixed dtypes:

```
In [7]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(3), 'b':np.ones(3)})                                                  
In [8]: df1                                                                                                     
Out[8]: 
   a    b
0  0  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  2  1.0
```

This is a copy, but doesn't owndata.  Note that this is `F_CONTIGUOUS`; I think that means there's a transpose in the generation code, which would account for the False owndata:

```
In [10]: df1.to_numpy().flags                                                                                   
Out[10]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  ...
In [11]: df1.to_numpy()                                                                                         
Out[11]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [2., 1.]])
```

The BlockManager has two blocks, one for each dtype:

```
In [12]: df1._data                                                                                              
Out[12]: 
BlockManager
Items: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
FloatBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 3, dtype: float64
IntBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 3, dtype: int64
```

`df1.values` is:

```
return self._data.as_array(transpose=self._AXIS_REVERSED)
```

`as_array` without transpose and with:

```
In [14]: df1._data.as_array()                                                                                   
Out[14]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
In [15]: df1._data.as_array(transpose=True)                                                                     
Out[15]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [2., 1.]])
```

So `to_numpy` uses `np.array(values)` with the potential of `copy` and `dtype`.  `values` passes the task BlockManager, which does at least one `np.asarray()` and a (probable) `transpose`.  If there are more than one block, it does an `_interleave` (which I haven't explored).

So while `to_numpy(copy=True)` ensures a copy, it's harder to predict/detect whether processing up to that point has created a copy or not.

Comment: I guess the answer to the question "when does `pd.DataFrame.to_numpy` return a view" is smth like "whenever the data frame consists of at most one block of data". Thanks for the work!

Answer (score 0):

To find out if any ndarray is a copy or a view into another array, you can use the owndata flag:

```
array.flags.owndata
```

The result, in both of the above cases, when running on my machine, was False.

As a side note, a couple of more examples of `owndata`:

```
a = np.arange(10)
print(a.flags.owndata) ==> True
b = a.reshape([5,2])
print(b.flags.owndata) ==> False.
```

Comment: `np.arange(3).reshape(3,1).flags.owndata`  is False too.

Comment: @hpaulj - see my additional note on the post.

Comment: Looking at code and flags, I think `owndata` will only be True if `.to_numpy(copy=True)` (or its dtype forces a change).  There's usually `transpose` earlier that will turn off `owndata`.

Comment: As you said, this flag can not distinguish between the two cases, so does not answer the question.