# Does scikit-learn train_test_split copy data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

Does the [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) method of scikit-learn duplicate the data? In other words, if I work with a large dataset, `X, y`, does it mean that after performing something like

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2023)
```

my data use twice as much memory as the original dataset? Or is there some scikit-learn (or basic python) magic that prevents it? (E.g., as using [`.to_numpy()` does not necessarily lead to data duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304176/how-to-find-out-dataframe-to-numpy-did-not-create-a-copy))

If the memory use does double, what is the best practical way around this problem? Perhaps, something like

```
X, X_test, y, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2023)
```

?

**Remark**
Using `np.shares_memor(X_train, X)` suggests that the data is indeed duplicated.

Comment: Given that `train_test_split` shuffles the examples, that would imply to me that sharing the memory would be impossible.

Comment: regarding the practical way around this problem, what I would do is simply shuffling an `np.arange(len(X.shape[0]))` and split it into train and test. Then use those indexes to access respective records of X and y

Comment: Reading about it, be sure to use 'basic' indexing because [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) will return a copy instead of a view