# How do i check if two slices intersect of an array?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have an 2d-array
`arr = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=object)` later i will have two slices that are in shape of (5,1) and (1,5) os they are  always 1-dimensional.

```
a = arr[1:2, 3:8] # Red

b = arr[0:5, 4:5] # Blue
```

How to tell mathematically in code whether the two slices are intersecting vertically at a point or not?

[image: visualization of the array]

previous attempts:
I tried to use `np.may_share_memory(a,b)`
but it returns True even they are not intersected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865261/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-shares-memory-and-numpy-may-share-memory

Comment: Do you know the slices?  For example I can show that 1:2 is a subset of 0:5.  And 4:5 within 3:8.  But just given the resulting `a`,`b` arrays it will trickier.

Comment: An intersection exists if it exists i,j such as `arr[i,j]` is in both slice. Such a `i,j` have to abide all constraints: `i≥1, i≥0, i<2, i<5` and `j>=3, j>=4, j<8, j<5`. Which is possible iff `1<5`, `0<2`, `3<5`, `4<8` (assuming that slices are not empty, that is that `1<2`, `0<5`, `3<8` and `4<5`). Generally speaking so, non-empty slices `arr[a:b,c:d]` and `arr[e:f,g:h]` intersect iff `a<f, e<b, c<h, g<d` (non-emptiness meaning that `a<b, c<d, e<f, g<h` is assumed)

Comment: `may_share_memory` has a `max_work` parameter, and cites `shares_memory` as a more thorough searching function.  You may have to give an example where one or the other gives a false result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `start < end` for each range and that `step == 1` (default), there's only two ways for a pair of ranges to not intersect on a given axis.

For each axis, compare the two lists' ranges on that axis, checking for overlap. (For example, check `1:2` vs `0:5` and `3:8` vs `4:5`.) If all axes show overlap, then the shapes overlap.

```py
def does_overlap(a_start, a_end, b_start, b_end):
    if a_start >= b_end: return False
    if b_start >= a_end: return False
    return True

results = does_overlap(1, 2, 0, 5) and does_overlap(3, 8, 4, 5) # True
```

---

Based on comments, it seems like your question might actually be "How do I get a slice's bounds after having created the slice?" numpy doesn't seem to offer a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the [`intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) function?

it will give you the common elements between two 1d-arrays. **If the input arrays are not 1-D, they will be flattened.**

Comment: Mostly all slices have common elements

Comment: Depending on the common elements will result in inacurate intersections later since two slices can have similar elements but are not intersecting