# Merge two files in Python PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I have two files from where I need to fetch information for `data analysis`. I am using **`Python Pandas`** for this. Any help on how to do this will be appreciated.

I already know how merge 2 files using Python - I am looking forward to achieve this job in `PANDAS` particularly.

Once 2 files merged then I need to get some analytical data out of it. Both these file do have same structure of data in `CSV` format.

Comment: Why do you want to merge the files in pandas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to read the csv files into dataframes and concatenate them this way

```py
frames = [pd.read_csv('f1.csv'), pd.read_csv('f2.csv')]
result = concat(frames,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks `farhawa`. That's exactly what I was looking for to.

Comment: my pleasure, for more details: [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: it's worth mentioning that you may wish to pass param `ignore_index=True` otherwise you may get duplicate index values

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar please take into consideration Edchum remark

Comment: and if i have two dataframes and i need to intersect them to find the same data in a column that has the same name in that two dataframes, is there any faster way than just iterate through these two columns?

Comment: Is that pd.concat or something else?

Answer (score 4):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

df_combined = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df_combined.to_csv(combined_file_name)
```

Comment: Isn't the problem of this that df1 and df2 will remain in memory, even if one would utilize only df_combined from that point onwards. Thus one basically stores the same data twice? Unless pd has some functionality that it doesn't copy, but only references df1, df2? In that case farhawa's solution is more efficient? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18295630/4959635