# Which is better to use when combining multiple data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to combine multiple Excel Files using the `pandas` data frames. Normally I could use `append` or `concat` but as the documentation says this will create a new object and re-assign it back to you.

The other method which I came across is by using the `loc` method and do `[df[len(df)] = df_dict for df_dict in def.to_dict('r')]` where df is another dataframe which i edit on the go.

I wanted to know which method is better to use, considering that we use this for a large amount of data so whatever makes it more efficient

Comment: Did you check the `copy` parameter of the `concat` function ?

Comment: it says `do not copy unnecessarily` however it does create a brand new dataframe object and return that to the calling convention.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295630/how-do-i-concatenate-pandas-dataframes-without-copying-the-data